# how to join tables without repeating column in mysql

Tags: mysql, join, where-clause, multiple-columns

i have two tables:

table1 (limit 5):

```
+--------------+
| TF_ID        |
+--------------+
| T139297_1.02 | 
| T025433_1.02 | 
| T025429_1.02 | 
| T045327_1.02 | 
| T088966_1.02 | 
+--------------+
```

table2 (limit 5):

```
+--------------+-----------+------------+-------------+
| TF_ID        | Family_ID | TSource_ID | DBID        |
| T000001_1.02 | F001_1.02 | TS19_1.02  | FBgn0085089 |
| T000002_1.02 | F002_1.02 | TS07_1.02  | AMAG_03406  | 
| T000003_1.02 | F002_1.02 | TS07_1.02  | AMAG_05299  | 
| T000004_1.02 | F002_1.02 | TS07_1.02  | AMAG_10904  |
| T000005_1.02 | F002_1.02 | TS07_1.02  | AMAG_15258  | 
+--------------+-----------+------------+-------------+
```

i want to join the two tables by the **TF_ID** column, i've tried this:

```
select a.TF_ID, b.TF_ID, b.Family_ID from table1 a, table2 b where a.TF_ID=b.TF_ID;
```

the output is like:

```
+--------------+--------------+-----------+
| TF_ID        | TF_ID        | Family_ID |
+--------------+--------------+-----------+
| T014411_1.02 | T014411_1.02 | F070_1.02 | 
| T014431_1.02 | T014431_1.02 | F070_1.02 | 
| T014439_1.02 | T014439_1.02 | F070_1.02 | 
| T014447_1.02 | T014447_1.02 | F070_1.02 | 
| T014450_1.02 | T014450_1.02 | F070_1.02 |
```

What should i do if i don't what the **TF_ID** colum to repeat?
i am new in database, please help

Comment: Just don't list it twice. You don't have to include it twice in your columns list.

Comment: you are manually selected that column so just remove it from query like `select a.TF_ID, b.Family_ID from table1 a, table2 b where a.TF_ID=b.TF_ID; `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just select it once; you don't have to select it twice. Example:

```
SELECT a.TF_ID, b.Family_ID
FROM table1 a, table2 b
WHERE a.TF_ID=b.TF_ID;
```

Even better, use `USING`:

```
SELECT a.TF_ID, b.Family_ID
FROM table1 a
    LEFT JOIN table2 b USING (TF_ID);
```

Answer (score 1):

select a.TF_ID, b.Family_ID, b.TSource_ID,b.DBID 
from table1 a 
left join table2 b on a.TF_ID=b.TF_ID;